# My laptop won't access the internet or copy/cut/paste

Tags: windows-7, laptop, anti-virus, internet-connection

I am not sure if this is related, but this started happening around when I removed Avira anti-virus and installed AVG, unaware that AVG is not compatible with my 64-bit machine. My Windows 7 operating system was also not genuine, so I had to get it back to the store to fix this, as I'd bought a laptop that didn't have a pre-installed OS (very bad idea). I removed AVG and re-installed Avira in Safe mode - no change.

I cannot move, cut, copy or paste anything. The anti-virus and Windows are able to scan and update, but I get a blank screen when I try to access the internet through my browser (I've tried both IE8 and Firefox). The store I got it from couldn't figure out the problem and suggested I just reformat, said it was probably a virus.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is re-installing the OS an option?

Comment: @soandos Not at the moment, as I don't have the CD.I was wondering if it was caused by anything I may have done.

Comment: It might be the *anti*-virus, too. Most of them install additional filters for scanning HTTP and other network traffic, and if the driver fails to load something like this *might* happen... (Not sure about clipboard though.)